# How to clear the field after typeahead selection?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using [ui.bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) after you select one of the options provided by typeahead how do you clear the value of the input?

http://plnkr.co/edit/yz4EtEJSTVekSemzxagC?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap']);


app.controller('createBundle', ['$scope', '$http', '$location',
    function($scope, $http, $location){
  $scope.products = [{name: 'One'}, {name: 'Two'}];

  $scope.bundle = {
    name: '',
    products: [],
    technologies: [],
    deliveryMethods: [],
  };

  $scope.addProduct = function(item, model, label){
    $scope.bundle.products.push(item);
  }

  $scope.resetProducts = function(){
    $scope.bundle.products = [];
  }

}]);
```

HTML

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="products" 
ng-model="tempProduct" 
typeahead="product.name for product in products | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
placeholder="Products" typeahead-on-select="addProduct($item, $model, $label)">
```

#### Solution

```
typeahead-on-select="addProduct($item, $model, $label);tempProduct=null"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `addProduct` function, you need to clear the model of the input

```
$scope.addProduct = function(item, model, label){
  $scope.bundle.products.push(item);
  $scope.tempProduct = null; //-- clear it
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using a service for addProduct etc. So I added the clear to the typeahead-on-select attribute. I edited my post to show the new value.

Answer (score 1):

I forked your source code to give you a proposal of how you could do it.

I made some changes and this is the result.
You can see it in this plunker link.

`$scope.addProduct = function(item){
        $scope.bundle.products.push(item);
        $scope.tempProduct = "";
      }`

http://plnkr.co/edit/9f7FsNEILQKdDN1GyUp6?p=info